# When watching a Git repo, can I remove a file from the Watch list? (10+ email notifications on this one file per day)

Tags: github

I get too many Git notifications due to one file in a large repo I need to Watch. How can I exclude it?

I end up deleting a lot of email notifications based on this one file.

Comment: That’s not possible as far as I know, you only have the available options from the drop down, noting else.